How can I upload files directly from a remote server mounted in Ubuntu's file manager?
I'm currently connecting to my institute server from my Ubuntu system by mounting it in the file manager GUI under "Other Locations" in Ubuntu with:

sftp://username@ip_address/

This setup gives me a local system-like experience. However, when I need to upload files to websites like GPT, I have to copy the files to my local system first. This process is inconvenient since I frequently update the files on the server.
Is there a simple one-time solution to this problem, possibly by using a different protocol or method?

Look into SSHFS. It allows you to mount a file system over SSH, which should work because you already have SFTP access.

Using sftp. Create an executable script something like this:
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads/
sftp -oPort=23 username@ip_address:/dir/ <<EOF
passive
put file1
get file2
del file3
exit
EOF

would use port 23 and "passive mode" to upload/download/delete file1/file2/file3 from/to/from ~/Downloads.
You can add all the commands you manually type into it.

A newer method would be to use scp:
scp username@ip_address://dir/file  ~/Downloads/

would download /dir/file from the remote server to ~/Downloads. You can use wildcards. The other way is just switching the 2:
scp ~/Downloads/file username@ip_address://dir/

This will upload ~/Downlods/file to ~/dir/` on the remote server.
It requires that the remote server is set up to handle this connection.  If needed you can use -P {portnumber} to use a specific port.
It also can be used to do remote to remote copy.
scp username@ip_address1://dir/file  username@ip_address2://dir/file

